# Webhook did not fire after subscribed WABA to application

Tags: webhooks, facebook-webhooks, whatsapp-cloud-api

In order to connect WhatsApp business with an application, I use embedding singup flow.

All seems well - I use `subscribed_apps` endpoints and get a successful response:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/[WABA_ID]/subscribed_apps' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]'
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
    "success": true
}
```

When I check this endpoint by 'GET' - I also see that my application has been configured correctly:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "whatsapp_business_api_data": {
                "link": "....",
                "name": "My Provider App",
                "id": "...."
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I send a message to the WhatsApp number connected to this account, the webhook does not fire (although it is well defined and properly tested).

What could be causing the problem?

Comment: how did you solve this? Have similar issues.

Comment: @AlexandruR. Version issues. When I took an older version of the META app - it worked properly.

You can follow my question in the community : https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/236199056179414/